# How can I customize the bottom toolbar in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to add a another tab for a python console to the bottom toolbar in IntelliJ, ideally accessible with a shortcut like alt+0. Googled for a while now, but I can't find a way. The only workaround would be to add a button for the python console to the top toolbar and then it opens in the `run` tab. I would prefer an extra tab specifically for python though.

Here is a screenshot in case it is unclear what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to duplicate the `Terminal` tool window.

But you can certainly do this instead:

[image]

By clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> icon, you can open a new terminal session, and you can rename it too.

The only drawback would be that if you click on the `TODO` tab for instance, and want to return to the regular terminal, you need to do two clicks (`Terminal` > `Local`).

Comment: Yeah I considered that too, but I think the best solution, if the toolbar cannot be customized, is to go with an external solution from my window manager. Thanks though!